# Why don't we need to use "was" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage, modal-verbs, literature

A quote from "The Great Gatsby".

> As if his absence quickened something within her, Daisy leaned forward again, **her voice glowing and singing**.

Do we need to use **was** before "glowing and singing"?

> I’ve got a nice place here,” he said, **his eyes flashing about restlessly**.

The same is here. I'd put the verb "**were**" in this sentence. Why is it ommited?

Comment: The construction is a perfectly ordinary (adverbial) ***participle phrase*** modifying the target verb ***leaned forward*** Which has noun ***Daisy*** as it's subject, so arguably you could say the participle phrase adjectivally modifies the noun, if that makes more sense to you. Note semantically, that nothing would change if the "subject" of the participle phrase (***her, his***, here) was elided / deleted. That's just another stylistic choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for your response. It's full and complete!  You helped me a lot.

Comment: As Paul says, if Fitzgerald wrote it, it might be "stylistically marked, unusual", but it couldn't possibly be "wrong". Note that although I said it's "perfectly ordinary", I think the truth is it's only really common as a relatively ***literary*** usage. Ordinary people in ordinary conversational contexts would probably include ***with*** or equivalent (again, as Paul says below), to clarify the relationship between the participle clause and whatever it refers to.

Comment: This kind of construction is also called an **absolute phrase**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So in ordinary conversation i would use "with" too  but, as you mentioned  above, we may consider it as a literary usage. Now i understand it better. Thx for help!

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "literary" usage as there are plenty of times when such a participial clause is used in everyday conversation. But it does tend to occur in narratives. "He came in the door, him dripping from head to toe, and I said stay where you are, I'll go and get a towel."

Comment: or "She was listening to the radio, the music blaring, and I said could you please turn that racket down."

Comment: @TimR: You mean you really might say "I was was listening to the radio, the music blaring, when the doorbell rang" without including ***with*** before ***the music***? Does no-one ever tell you you talk like a book? :) Also I gotta say that re-stating the subject in "He came in the door, **him** dripping from head to toe..." sounds weird / dialectal to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I watch movies made in Ireland, sometimes the language sounds much like what I've heard all my life; my mother's family are originally from Ireland and there are many families of Irish descent in the county.  Maybe that's what you're hearing.

Comment: @TimR: You're definitely right that Irish speakers in particular tend to repeat pronoun subjects (like ***him** dripping...* above). I have no preconceptions as to whether they're any more likely to drop ***with*** before ***the music*** in the other example, but perhaps they do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To my ear,  "the music blaring" is much more emphatic and emotional than "*with* the music blaring". But I might well say "with the bass turned up." "The guy was driving his car around the neighborhood with the bass turned up."

Comment: @TimR: I think that's my point. A "bare" adverbial clause like "the music blaring"  is much more emphatic and emotional *and literary* than the same element receded by ***with***. I suggest that's because the reader / audience must engage more with the text in order to work out for themselves how the adverbial clause relates to the rest of the utterance. Which is all very well in *written* contexts - I just think it sounds a bit "flowery" for ordinary conversational contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But I wouldn't call it specifically "literary". It occurs in everyday conversational "narratives" where it isn't "flowery" at all, simply emphatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Do we need to?” Well, given that Fitzgerald is considered one of the greats of twentieth-century American literature, it’s safe to conclude that your quotes demonstrate convincingly that, no, we do not.

In fact, inserting *was* in the first would turn that perfectly idiomatic English sentence into a run-on mashup of two sentences.

Compare it to “He walked in proud, his head held high.” You can think of it as having had a *with* elided.

Comment: Take it easy, please) i didn't wanna say that Fitzgerald was wrong. I just wanted to know how this phrase was constructed by one of the greatest writers of all time. So do not take it amiss and thanks for answering. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Strider1996: There are lots of brilliant writers who use incomplete sentences and otherwise break rules of grammar. In this case, Fitzgerald didn't, but just because a sentence comes from a brilliant novelist, it doesn't mean it's grammatical.